# Exclusive conditions and execution of branches

Tags: java, if-statement, branch

Suppose you have 4 conditions exclusive from each other and you want to execute every branch if the corresponding condition is met.How do you do this?

Comment: If the code block after ‘if’ is bigger than 3-4 lines,consider refactoring it to method ‘validateIfPresent’ followed by ‘executeIfAbsent’ …. with if check inside it

Comment: Nested `if` blocks, for example: `if (condition1IsTrue) { /* do whatever... */ if (condition2IsTrue) { /* do whatever... */ if (condition3IsTrue) { /* do whatever... */ if (condition4IsTrue) { /* do whatever... */ } } } }`.